# SVN Local Repository

Tags: apache, svn, version-control, nutch

I imported Apache Nutch source code into my local ubuntu installation. I have subversion installed on my eclipse kepler. The sourcecode has several branches and one main project in trunk. I was thinking of specifying this source-code location as my repo location to svn and check out & or commit changes based off of this. However SVN always seem to expect a remote repo location. Is there anyway I can make this dumping ground of apache nutch source code as my repo location for svn?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

DVCS systems may help, such as git, Hg, etc.
Subversion is a centerized version control system, all workspaces directly connect to center repository.
But DVCS have local repository, before you commit to remote repository, you need commit to local rep first.